# Sitemap.xml redirect rule creates a "page not found" error

Tags: .htaccess-configuration, server-configuration

I have the need to create a sitemap.xml static URL for my dynamic sitemap Joomla component, because GTranslate requires access to /sitemap.xml

I have put a redirectrule, which used to work up to a few months ago, but this is generate a sitemap.xml with a "page not found" error in it.

So the sitemap works well index.php?option=com_jmap&view=sitemap&format=xml but when the redirect is in place, this weird error comes up. [image: page not found]

These are the contents of the .htaccess file up to the rule, I've tried using various options, but nothing seems to be working.

```
RewriteOptions inherit
#commented out since it seems wrong directory
#suPHP_ConfigPath /home/dartcr6/public_html 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ /index.php?option=com_jmap&view=sitemap&format=xml [NC,L]

DirectoryIndex  index.php
# These were commented out - fixed the URL from dart-creations.com to collectiveray.com
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^collectiveray.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.collectiveray.com/$1 [R=301,L]

### marker WEBP start ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "image/webp"si
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+webp]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone.*Version/(\d{2}).*Safari
RewriteCond %1 >13
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+webp]
### marker WEBP end ###
```

Could do with some guidance :-)

TIA

Comment: Have you resolved this? I've just tried requesting  the `sitemap.xml` URL in your screenshot and it appears to be working OK?